# Images in email is showing as attachment in Hotmail or Gmail

Tags: image, email, outlook

I’m sending the email using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem, it is a html email with some images in its body, i m sending images as attachments like this

```
mailItem.Attachments.Add(path + "Header.png", (int)OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, "Header");
```

then setting the body

```
string body=”<img src="cid:{0}" width="627" height="125" alt="Header">”
mailItem.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;                
mailItem.HTMLBody = string.Format(body, "Header.png") ;
```

Everything is working fine in MS outlook, but image are showing as attachment in Hotmail(outlook.com) and Gmail, but in MS outlook images are showing in body where they should be display

I search and found a solution like that if i set cid for my images like domain name e.g. Header.png@somedomain.com then it will work, but it is not working and warning appears of malicious attachment when i set this type of name for attachments

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying the cid attribute for the header, but you never set the Content-ID MIME header. For it to be set when the message is converted to MIME, you need to set the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID MAPI property (DASL name "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F") using Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
but i try the following code, and still the issue is not resolved,
either i m not getting the correct syntax

`Attachment a=mailItem.Attachments.Add(path + "Header.png", (int)OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, "Header"); 

a.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F",
                                                   "Header.png@somedomain.com");

a.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F",
                                                   "Header.png");
`

Comment: I set the property using the below code
`mailItem.Attachments[counter - 1].PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(                        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "header.png");`
But still the issue is not resolved,

Comment: Do you see PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property set correctly in OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) if you click IMessage, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab and open the attachment. Is your HTML correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is one you can embed image it will be embedded in both Hotmail and Gmail:
**This code is in python 3.9.1.**

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("outlook.application")
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
attachment = mail.Attachments.Add(embedImgPath) 
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F","MyId1")
mail.HTMLBody = f"<html><body> {htmlbody} <br> <img src="" cid:MyId1""> </body></html>"
mail.send()
```