# embedded images sent via outlook with html body are not shown on smartphones

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, outlook

i have made a lot of search over the net but could not find any solution for that issue.
my desktop app need to send an email via users outlook.
everything is working properly except that the embedded images are missing on smartphones(tested on iphone and few android phones).
also tested on outlook client outside the local network (i am mentioning this because the 'src' of the html image is on the local network of the sender) and everything is working properly (i`m using "cid" for the path), so the problem is probably not the path of the image.

here are the importent parts of my test code:

```
 Public Sub Test()
        Dim file As String = "\\netapp2\Public\All\INTERNET PROJECTS\Pf-PMS\jonathana\DIVISION REPORT 25-12-2015(2)\DIVISION REPORT 25-12-2015-04-58-45.xlsm"
        Dim filetosave As String = "\\netapp2\Public\All\INTERNET PROJECTS\Pf-PMS\jonathana\DIVISION REPORT 25-12-2015(4)\IMAGES"
        Dim a() As String = {filetosave & "\backlog.png", filetosave & "\Teams.png", filetosave & "\q.png"}

        Dim b = "<div>" _
& "<p>" _
& "text*text*text " & Now.ToString & "<br/><br/>" & "text*text*text" _
& "<br/>" _
& "text*text*text" _
& "<br/>" _
& "text*text*text" _
& "<br/>" _
& "<br/>" _
& "<u><b>text*text*text</u></b> " _
& "<br/>" _
& "<img alt='BACKLOG TABLE' hspace=0 src='cid:backlog.png' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;" _
& "<br/>" _
& "</p>" _
& "</div> " _
& "<br/>" _
& "<br/>" _
& "<div> " _
& "<p>" _
& "<u><b>text*text*text </u></b>" _
& "<br/>" _
& "<IMG alt='ORANGE TEAMS DISTRIBUTION' hspace=0 src='cid:Teams.png' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;" _
& "<br/>" _
& "</p>" _
& "</div> " _
& "<br/>" _
& "<br/>" _
& "<div> " _
& "<p>" _
& "<u><b>text*text*text </u></b>" _
& "<br/>" _
& "<IMG alt='DISTRIBUTION' hspace=0 src='cid:q.png' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;" _
& "<br/>" _
& "</p>" _
& "</div> " _
& "<br/>"


        Dim subject As String = text*text*text"
        SendHtmlEmailMessegeWithMultipleAtachments(subject, b, GeneralInformation.InfoStructue.UserEmail & ";XXX@012.net.il", "", "DIVISION_REPORT", a)
    End Sub

    Sub SendHtmlEmailMessegeWithMultipleAtachments(ByVal sSubject As String, ByVal sBody As String, ByVal sTo As String, ByVal sCC As String, _
                     ByVal sDisplayname As String, Optional ByVal sFilename() As String = Nothing)

        Try

            Dim oApp As Interop.Outlook._Application
            oApp = New Interop.Outlook.Application

            Dim oMsg As Interop.Outlook._MailItem
            oMsg = oApp.CreateItem(Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)

            oMsg.Subject = sSubject
            oMsg.To = sTo
            oMsg.CC = sCC
            oMsg.HTMLBody = "<html><body dir=RTL>" & sBody & "</body></html>"


            Dim strN As String = sDisplayname


            If sFilename.Length > 0 Then
                Dim sBodyLen As Integer = Int(sBody.Length)
                Dim oAttachs As Interop.Outlook.Attachments = oMsg.Attachments
                Dim oAttach As Interop.Outlook.Attachment

                For Each itm In sFilename
                    oAttach = oAttachs.Add(itm.ToString)
                Next


            End If
            oMsg.Save()
            oMsg.Send()


            oApp = Nothing
            oMsg = Nothing
            IsOpen = Nothing

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("ERROR:" & ex.ToString, vbCritical + vbMsgBoxRight, "ERROR")
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property to the value matching the cid attribute for the image in the HTML body.

```
oAttach = oAttachs.Add(itm.ToString)
oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "backlog.png'
```

Comment: hi @Dimitry and thank you for the response. that seems to be the solution but i keep getting that exception: A first chance exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
System.MissingMemberException: Public member 'SetPropety' on type 'PropertyAccessor' not found.

Comment: also tryed changing the syntax from this thread but still cant solve it...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720288/images-in-email-is-showing-as-attachment-in-hotmail-or-gmail

Comment: OK... tryed alot o f variations, now with this syntax i get exception that one of the parameters is illegal: oMsg.Attachments.Add(sFilename(0).ToString, , sBodyLen, "backlog.png").PropertyAccessor.SetProperties("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "backlog.png")

Comment: It needs to be SetProperty - "r" was missing.

Comment: OK SOLVED !!! that wasn`t the 'r' i have allready fixed that. thank you very much @Dmitry for helping me dealing with one of the most frustrating issues that I had. that is the syntax:  oMsg.Attachments.Add(sFilename(0).ToString, , sBodyLen, "backlog.png").PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "backlog.png")